# echarts - how to plot two time series with different dates

Tags: time-series, echarts

When using echarts: is there a way to plot two time series with different dates?

An example is explained here: https://peltiertech.com/plot-two-time-series-with-different-dates/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Stacked Line chart](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=line-stack)

```
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked line'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    legend: {
        data:['first','second']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['12/1/2018','12/2/2018','12/3/2018','12/4/2018','12/5/2018','12/6/2018','12/7/2018']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name:'first',
            type:'line',
            data:[120, 132, 121, 134, , 200, 210]
        },
        {
            name:'second',
            type:'line',
            data:[220, 182, , 234, 290, 100, 310]
        }
    ]
};
```

[image: stacked-line-chart]

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I don't see how this can solve my problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you please show example of a chart you want to create? the post contains a lot of images.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. I have the following example data:

```
 xAxisData = ['08:00', '08:05', '08:10', '08:15', '08:20', '08:25', '08:30'];

  legendData = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'];
  data= [
    [20.10, 30.10, null, null],
    [10.99, 53.10, null, null],
    [null, null, 5.3, 60],
    [33.10, 60.10, null, null],
    [null, null, 8.3, 40],
    [26.10, 88.10, null, null],
    [null, null, 12, 20]
  ];
```

These data I want to display in a line chart

The solution is to set the "connectNulls" property to **true** on your **line** series data: